# How to force the derived class to override a method that returns its class name only?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I don't know what pattern I have to implement for forcing the derived class to override the method `Print` returning only its class name.

```
class Base
{
    protected virtual string Print() => nameof(Base);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base b = new Derived();
        Console.WriteLine(b.Print());
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override string Print() => nameof(Derived);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce what you need by implementing generic logic in the base class:

```cs
protected string Print() => this.GetType().Name;
```

That way, if you call the method from `Base`, you will always get derived class name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some generics and type constraint on the base class. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new Derived();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Print());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public abstract class Base<TChild>
        where TChild : Base<TChild>
    {
        public string Print() => typeof(TChild).Name;
    }

    public class Derived : Base<Derived>
    {
    }
```

Comment: How can abstract help force ...?

Comment: It will force the child classes to implement the member. Updated answer

Comment: But you  still allow the `Derived` to return `"Hello World"` instead of `nameof(Derived)`.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are getting at better now. What are you trying to accomplish

Comment: The problem is that you can do `public class Another : Base<Derived>`.

Comment: Agreed, not the optimal solution. GetType is better.